# increment sum of score in ajax not working

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have a table of `encouragements` with 2 fields `unit_score' and`max_score` in database. and I'm working on developing a very simple score system and as a proof of concept I have a div with a laravel defined variable that is supposed to be incremented by 1 when the button is clicked. What I have so far is working, but only once... Why does the votes value not continue to go up when the button is clicked?

[image: database]

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            @foreach($encouragements as $encouragement)
                <tr>
                    <th class="translate">{{ $encouragement->title }}</th>
                    <td>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" min="{{ $encouragement->unit_score }}" max="{{ $encouragement->max_score }}" id="num{{$encouragement->id}}" value="0" class="form-control col-sm-1 translate" name="encouragement[{{ $encouragement->id }}]">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                    <input type="button" onclick="incrementValue({{$encouragement->id}})" class="btn btn-warning" value="Add">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="text-right">Sum:
        <span id="sum" class="translate">0</span>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
function incrementValue(id)
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('num'+id).value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    document.getElementById('num'+id).value = value;
    values = value + value;
    document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML = values;
}
</script>
```

Comment: your title is misleading btw. You say your AJAX is not working, but there is no AJAX used in your script at all.
Please share more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Put your JS function within a `<script>` tag.

Comment: I put my JS function in a <script> tag.

Comment: do you have any error in the console tab of your browser that you can share?